# linux: (sh script) can not combine date variables in single command

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm trying to run some commands that require date begin and end arguments, but when I combine `dateFrom` and `dateTo` variables it's missing from start.

Please check my code and output last line, Thanks.

```
#! /bin/bash
dateFrom=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
dateTo=$(date --date="-7 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
echo "dateFrom: $dateFrom"
echo "dateTo: $dateTo"
echo "dateFrom: $dateFrom, dateTo: $dateTo"
```

output

```
dateFrom: 2020-04-23
dateTo: 2020-04-16
, dateTo: 2020-04-16
```

Comment: Your file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: Your script file has DOS/Windows line endings, which is putting carriage return characters in your variables. See: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: i have removed. but output still same.

Comment: How did you remove dos line endings? Try: `tr -d '\r' <{file.dos} >{file}` where `{file.dos}` is the "wrong" file and `{file}` shall be the new file without the DOS line-endings.

Comment: just go to very last line and hit backspace :D . i don't know how to use it. but problem solved thank you guys all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem due to the presence of DOS line terminators in the bash-script file.

I wrote and use the bash-script in the following lines to solve the issue.

This script will remove the `\r` chars from a specified file after it will have generate a copy of the original file.

You may copy this script as `dos2unix.sh` and call it as:

```
/home/user: ./dos2unix.sh filename<enter>
```

The execution will generate two files: `filenames.dos`, that is the original, and `filename` that is the file cleaned from the `\r` chars.

```
#!/bin/bash

program=$(basename $0)

if test $# -lt 1
then
  echo "usage: $program filename"
  echo -e "\nThe original file will be copied as filename.dos"
  exit 1
fi

cp $1 $1.dos

tr -d '\r' <$1.dos >$1
```

Note: Remember to execute: chmod +x dos2unix.sh!

Comment: Bye! Good luck, dude ;)